# Create a subdirectory for all directories in folder

Tags: bash, shell, directory

Suppose I have some directory, which contain a number of subdirectories, and in each of those subdirectories I want to create a directory with the same name:

```
./dir-1
./dir-2
...
./dir-n
```

I want to do `mkdir */new-dir`

but this throws an error. What's the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for dir in $(ls); do
  mkdir "$dir/new-dir"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type d | xargs -I "{x}" mkdir "{x}"/new-dir
```

If you want to reduce it to the first level of directories use

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -I "{x}" mkdir "{x}"/new-dir
```

Answer (score 2):

Amazing that this question never obtained a sane answer:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in */; do
    mkdir -- "${i}newdir"
done
```

- This is 100% safe regarding funny symbols in filenames (spaces, wildcards, etc.).
- The `shopt -s nullglob` so that the glob expands to nothing if there are no matches.
- The `--` in `mkdir` to mark the end of options (if there's a directory with a name starting with a hyphen, doesn't confuse `mkdir` trying to interpret it as an option).

This silently ignores the hidden directories. If you need to perform this operation on hidden directories, just replace the line `shopt -s nullglob` by the following:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
```

The `dotglob` so that the globs also consider hidden files/directories.

If you want only one invocation of `mkdir`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
dirs=( */ )
mkdir -- "${dirs[@]/%/newdir}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to list only the directories otherwise you may get a bunch of errors when it encounters a file instead of a directory

`for dir in $(ls -d */); do
        mkdir "$dir/2015"
done`